# ¿Como puedo eliminar y modificar registros?

Tags: php, mysql

La cosa es que estoy creando una tabla donde quiero que el dato ya insertado se pueda modificar o eliminar. El problema es que no tengo idea de como hacerlo en mi modelo de pagina. el modelo es "Modelo Vista Controlador". Alguna ayuda?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay les dejo unos ejemplos de mi codigo.

**Categoria.php**

```
class Categoria {
private $id;
private $nombre;
private $db;

//CONEXION DB
public function __construct() {
    $this->db = DataBase::connect();
}

function getId() {
    return $this->id;
}

function getNombre() {
    return $this->nombre;
}

function setId($id) {
    $this->id = $id;
}

function setNombre($nombre) {
    $this->nombre = $this->db->real_escape_string($nombre);
}

public function getAll(){
    $categorias = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM categorias ORDER BY id DESC;");
    return $categorias;
}

public function save(){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO categorias VALUES(NULL,'{$this->getNombre()}');";
    $save = $this->db->query($sql);

    $result = false;
    if($save){
        $result = true;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

}

**CategoriaController.php**

require_once 'models/categoria.php';

class CategoriaController{

```
public function index(){
    Utils::isAdmin();
    $categoria = new Categoria();
    $categorias = $categoria->getAll();

    require_once 'views/categoria/index.php';
}

public function crear(){
    Utils::isAdmin();
    require_once 'views/categoria/crear.php';
}

public function modificar(){
    Utils::isAdmin();
    require_once 'views/categoria/modificar.php';
}

public function save(){
    Utils::isAdmin();

    if(isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['nombre'])){
        //GUARDAR LA CATEGORIA EN BD
        $categoria = new Categoria();
        $categoria->setNombre($_POST['nombre']);
        $save = $categoria->save();
    }
    header('location:'.base_url.'categoria/index');
}
```

}

**index.php**

DIRTER | REGISTRO

```
<div id="presentacion">

    <!--BARRA DE NAVEGACION-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light navbar-expand-md py-2 shadow">
      <!--CONTAINER-->
      <div class="container">
        <!--LOGO-->
        <a href="<?=base_url?>" class="navbar-brand border-bottom">DIRTER</a>

      </div><!--FIN CONTAINER-->
    </nav><!--FIN BARRA NAVEGACION-->


    <!--CONTAINER-->
    <section class="container">  

        <a href="<?=base_url?>categoria/crear" class="btn btn-secondary rounded mt-3 btn-block">Crear categoria</a>

        <table class="table table-hover border mb-5" id="tabla-categoria">
            <thead class="thead-light">
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th class="col-md-7">NOMBRE</th>
                    <th colspan="2">OPERACIONES</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <?php while($cat = $categorias->fetch_object()): ?>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><?= $cat->id; ?></td>
                    <td><?= $cat->nombre; ?></td>
                    <td><a href="<?=base_url?>categoria/modificar" class="px-3 py-1"><i class="fas fa-edit text-dark"></i></a></td>
                    <td><a href="<?=base_url?>categoria/eliminar" class="px-3 py-1"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt text-dark"></i></a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </table> 
    </section>
</div>
```

Gracias por tu atención.

Comment: Se utiliza ajax para estas ocasiones ya que ejecuta una consulta de un fichero externo sin tener que recargar la página

Comment: Me falta tiempo para darte una respuesta completa, pero viendo el contexto, te pedo indicar que en método `modificar()` debería recibir el `id` de la categoría, para poder recuperar los datos y mostrarlos en la vista `.../modificar.php`, así mismo el formulario de esta vista debería apuntar aún método que actualice los datos, por ejemplo `update()` o `actualizar()` que recibirá el `id` y los valores para actualizar el registro. En cuanto a la eliminación fata ría un método `destroy()` o `eliminar()` que debe reibir el `id` del registro a eliminar y ejecutar la sentencia sobre la base de datos.

Comment: En cuanto al modelo, añadiría los métodos,  `delete()`, `get()` y `create()`. `delete()` para eliminar un registro por id, `get()` para recuperar un registro por id, `create()` haría la función que actualmente hace `save()` y `save()` lo utilizaría para actualizar un registro por id

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! eso si me ayuda mucho!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizamos ajax (yo lo utilizaré mediante JQuery ya que es más sencillo, pero se puede utilizar con javascript normal).

Crearemos 2 ficheros `.php`, uno ejecutar la consulta de actualizar y otro para borrar, les llamaremos por ejemplo `actualizar.php` y `borrar.php`. Luego a través de javascript o JQuery ejecutamos un evento de click y ejecutaremos el ajax.

Para lograr esto en vez de poner un `<a>` como has puesto, utilizaremos un `<span>` lo cambiaremos por una simple razón: no necesitamos ir a ningún sitio en (a diferencia del a). Se puede utilizar también un `<div>`

**Importante** poner una clase y no un id, ya que los id son únicos tu tienes `n` elementos

**Botones:**

```
<td><span class="modificar px-3 py-1"><i class="fas fa-edit text-dark"></i></span></td>
<td><span class="eliminar px-3 py-1"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt text-dark"></i></span></td>
```

**JQuery Borrar:**

```
   $(".eliminar").click(function(){
      var fila=$(this).parent().parent();
      var id =fila.find("td:first-child").html();
      if(confirm("Desea de verdad eliminar el "+id+"?")==true){
         jQuery.ajax({
           url:"eliminar.php",
           type:"POST",
           data:{del_id:id},
           success:function(){
              $(fila).fadeOut(function(){
                  $(this).remove();
              });
           },
           error:function(errors){
                  alert("Error: "+errors);
           }
         });
      }
   });
```

Para la parte de modificación haremos que cuando clicke en el icono el contenido se pueda editar mediante un input, para ello necesitaremos añadirle a la `td` del nombre una clase y un input. (Presupongo que el id es un campo auto_incrementativo)

```
<td class="nombre"><input type="hidden" name="nombre" val=<?= $cat->nombre; ?>></td>
```

Cuanto clickes la 1º vez se cambiará la clase por otra clase de esa forma podrás controlar 2 acciones en un mismo botón

**JQuery Modificar:**

```
   $(".modificar").click(function(){
      $(this).addClass("modificar2");
      $(this).removeClass("modificar");
      var fila=$(this).parent().parent();
      var id =fila.find("td:first-child").html();
      $(fila).find(".nombre").find("input").attr("type","text");
   });
   $(".modificar2").click(function(){
      $(this).addClass("modificar");
      $(this).removeClass("modificar2");
      var fila=$(this).parent().parent();
      var id =fila.find("td:first-child").html();
      if(confirm("Desea de verdad eliminar el "+id+"?")==true){
         $(fila).find(".nombre").find("input").attr("type","hidden");
         var valor=$(fila).find(".nombre").find("input").val();

         jQuery.ajax({
           url:"modificar.php",
           type:"POST",
           data:{upd_id:id,nombre:valor},
           success:function(){
              $('#tabla-categoria').load("#tabla-categoria");
           },
           error:function(errors){
                  alert("Error: "+errors);
           }
         });
      }
   });
```

Comment: Gracias!!! Pero tengo un pequeño problema como crees que lo pueda implementar en mi modelo mvc? por lo demás excelente respuesta!

Comment: Por lo que tengo entendido ajax esta basado en javascript por lo que es parte de la "vista". Puedes crear una carpeta llamada de js y añadir el código ahí. **Recuerda que tienes que añadir la librerira de JQuery para este código**

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Hola steve puedes usar Ajax para esta ocasión

Ejemplo

```
 $('#BorrarRegistro').click( function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var form = $('#modal-body2 form'),
        url = 'fichero.php',
        method = $('input[name=_method]').val() == undefined ? 'POST' : 'PUT';

    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        method: method,
        success: function (response) {
            //con esto actualizas la tabla
            $('#idTabla').load(" #idTabla");
        },
        error : function(xhr) {
            alert('error');
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Gracias! por el aporte amigo!